# Dealing with side effects: helper function to chain constructor and setup method

Tags: scala, functional-programming, method-chaining, side-effects

When working with existing libraries (can't edit constructors or companion objects) I often find that I need to call an init/setup procedure on an object and then return the object itself. I usually end up doing something like the following.

```
def createObject: MyObject = {
    val o = new MyObject
    o.init()
    o
}
```

This is IMHO *not* very elegant and I'm wondering if there's a better way of doing this, *e.g.*, a *setup-and-get* function along the lines of:

```
def createObject: MyObject = {
    setupAndGet(new MyObject) { _.init(v) }
}
```

Are there any existing solutions to this in Scala (besides writing my own)?

Comment: This isn't "functional-style." `o.store` acts by side-effect, so you are unlikely to find a built in way of doing what you want in Scala.

Answer (score 2):

Well, each Scala case class come with a generated companion object that has an `apply` method that has this exact signature.

```
scala> case class Foo(s:String)
defined class Foo

scala> Foo.apply("hello")
res1: Foo = Foo(hello)
```

Note that the `.apply()` method is the default method call, you can simply write `Foo("hello")`

Answer (score 1):

The following may be what you want.

```
def applyAndGet(myObject: MyObject)(f: myObject.type => Unit): myObject.type = {
  f(myObject)
  myObject
}
```

But I will recommend calling a constructor like `new MyObject(value)`.

Comment: That would work, but I was looking for a possible "built-in" way of doing it without writing a custom function.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following extension method (there is plenty of information about them, just google if you do not know what they are):

```
implicit class SetupExtension[T](private val t: T) extends AnyVal {
  def setup(code: T => Any): T = {
   code(t)
   t
  }
}
val s: MyObject = new MyObject.setup(_.setXProperty(???))
```

This method is quite usefull when you are working with some mutable api (from java libraries etc.). Other than that i would not recommend doing things this way.